# Pandas return separate column value in current index if two separate columns match

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following data frame:

```
  A    B    C
0 n1   n2   n4
1 n2   n3   n5
2 n3   n1   n6
```

I have been trying to:

1. Loop through `Column A` to find a matching value in `Column B`
2. If there is a match in `Column B` I want to grab the value in `Column C` *for the current index* and create a `Column D` with that value.
3. Given the example data frame above, below would be the solution I'm trying to achieve.

```
  A    B    C    D
0 n1   n2   n4   n6
1 n2   n3   n5   n4
2 n3   n1   n6   n5
```

I've seen lots of answers for excel utilizing match and index, but I literally can't find anything to help me solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map` with `set_index`:

```
df['D'] = df['A'].map(df.set_index('B')['C'])
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  n1  n2  n4  n6
1  n2  n3  n5  n4
2  n3  n1  n6  n5
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is using [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

```
df['D'] = df.set_index('B').reindex(df['A'])['C'].values
df

    A   B   C   D
0  n1  n2  n4  n6
1  n2  n3  n5  n4
2  n3  n1  n6  n5
```